# How do I host a server?

Tags: web-applications, webserver, html

I know you can host webpages by having a server on your home internet running... But that can lead to bandwidth problems. I was wondering if it would be possible to upload my code to a free server hosting website and have them host my site for me... I tried googleing but being a noob I couldn't understand if what I found was what I wanted. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have bandwidth problems hosting a server at home unless you have some really incredible growth.  If you're just dorking around then it's not really an issue.  The big deal is you have to open your network to the world, and this just isn't safe.

There are freebie providers, but you'll have to decide what you want to do.  You will also probably be exposing your users to advertising of the hosting provider's choice, which may not be what you want (remember: if you're not paying for a product, you are the product).

If you just want to blog and do some minor picture sharing and stuff, you might try starting out with [Blogger.com](http://www.blogger.com).  It's a Google property, is somewhat configurable, and you can export your blog if you want to migrate to something better later on.